# How to read string as enum class in Play Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

In Scala with Play and Slick, I've implemented enum Country as a case class, and would like to read/write it to JSON as a string. This is the complete code:

```
package models.enums

import play.api.libs.json._
import slick.lifted.MappedTo

case class Country(id: String) extends MappedTo[String] {  
  override def value: String = id
}

object Country {
  val France = Country("FR")
  val Germany = Country("DE")

  implicit val writes =  Writes[Country](
    (site: Country) => JsString(site.value)
  )

  // this line I need help with
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Country]
}
```

The Country enum is used by other models, e.g.

```
{
  "name": "Robo"
  "country": "DE"
}
```

The code above writes the enum as a plain String which is what I want, but I can't figure out how to implement the implicit read part. Currently the read would only work if the JSON is like:

```
{
  "name": "Robo"
  "country": {
    "id": "DE"
  }
}
```

I'm sure the answer is simple, just can't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Your JSONs are missing commas between field declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

implicit val reads = new Reads[Country] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Country] = for {
    id <- (json \ "country").validate[String]
  } yield Country(id)
}
```

`(json \ "country").validate[String]` returns a `JsResult[String]` which is then mapped (via `yield`) to a `JsResult[Country]`

**or**

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

implicit val reads = new Reads[Country] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Country] =
    (json \ "country").validate[String].map(Country(_))
```

**or**

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val reads: Reads[Country] = (__ \ "country").reads[String].map(Country(_))
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding your comment on validation, I'd just add that to your case class, not the json parser:

```
case class Country(id: String) extends MappedTo[String] {
  private val validIds = Set(France, Germany).map(_.id)

  require(validIds contains id, s"id must be one of $validIds")

  override def value: String = id
}
```

the trick is that statements you put in the body of your class will be part of the constructor. The `require` call there will throw an exception if anyone tries to create a `Country` with an ID which is not in your list of allowed IDs.

Comment: Thanks a ton, almost there. Is there a way to ensure the value is only one of the defined "enum", i.e. DE or FR? Currently, if the string is UK, the code allows it.

Comment: @Robo I added a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using sealed class. If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a sealed class, the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a possibility of a `MatchError` being raised at run-time.

Example from my project:

```
import com.pellucid.sealerate
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed abstract class TokenKind(val value: String)

object TokenKind {

  case object PasswordReset extends TokenKind("passwordReset")
  case object AccountConfirmation extends TokenKind("accountConfirmation")

  def values: Set[TokenKind] = sealerate.values[TokenKind]

  def apply(value: String): TokenKind = values.find(_.value == value).getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Can't construct TokenKind from: $value"))

  implicit def tokenKindWrites = new Writes[TokenKind] {
    override def writes(o: TokenKind): JsValue = JsString(o.value)
  }

  implicit def tokenKindReads = new Reads[TokenKind] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[TokenKind] = json match {
      case JsString(string) => JsSuccess(TokenKind(string))
      case _ => JsError("validate.error.invalidTokenKind")
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that solved this way:

```
object VoteType extends Enumeration {
  val Up, Down = Value

  implicit val voteTypeMappeer = MappedColumnType.base[VoteType.Value, String](_.toString, VoteType.withName)
}
```